aiohttp with proxy and cookies not working
I have been attempting to learn how to use aiohttp for a while to make requests asynchronously. I have been stuck in making a request that uses both cookies and proxies on it.
This is my current code:
async def proccessData():
    try:
        print("start 1")
        async with ClientSession(cookies=cookie) as session:
            print("start 2")
            async with session.get(url, proxy=prox, ssl=False) as response:
                print("start 3")
                print(response.status)
    except Exception as error:
        print(error)
        pass

asyncio.run(proccessData())

It prints out "start 1" and "start 2" but doesn't print "start 3" or the response's status, and instead errors out by saying the url + ":443 ssl:False [The parameter is incorrect]"
I have tried doing the request synchronously and it gives me no errors, anything I am missing or ignoring? Any help is appreciated

Well, let's start with the full traceback of the error.
